# How to convert a character into a 8-bit binary number and returns the result as a string

Tags: java, binary, ascii

So far i have this method and im not sure if its right.... but how do i convert a character into a 8-bit binary number and returns the result as a string?

```
 //method converts a 8-bit binary number into a character and returns the character


public static char convertToString(String binary)
  {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter a series of binary numbers");
  binary = input.next();


  int len = binary.length();
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
      System.out.print(binary.charAt(len-i-1) + " ");
      char temp = binary.charAt(len-i-1);
      int a = Character.getNumericValue(temp);
      int value = (int)(a * Math.pow(2, i));
      System.out.println(value);
      sum +=value;
     }
    char word = (char)sum;
    return word;
   }


  public static String convertToBinary(char character)
   {

    return "";
   }
```

Comment: Check Integer.toBinaryString(x)

Comment: While you will undoubtedly learn from this exercise, you should know that `char` is a 16-bit value and some characters, such as , might need two inseparable `char` values to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes. Highly optimized.

```
public static int binaryToValue(String binary)
{
   int sum = 0;
   int bit = 0;
   for (int i = binary.length(); --i >= 0;)
   {
      char temp = binary.charAt(i);
      int v = temp - '0';
      sum += v << bit;
      bit++;
   }
   return sum; // you may change the return type to char and cast this as return (char)sum
}


    public static String valueToBinary(char character)
    {
       char []ret = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
       int v = (int)character & 0xFFFF;
       //System.out.println(v);
       for (int idx = 0; v > 0; v >>= 1, idx++)
          if ((v & 1) == 1)
             ret[7-idx] = '1';
      return new String(ret);
    }


    public void initUI()
    {
       System.out.println(binaryToValue("1001"));
       System.out.println(valueToBinary('A')); // 65
       System.out.println(binaryToValue(valueToBinary('A')));

       MainWindow.exit(0);
    }
```

Note that in Java there are methods to do this, but since i'm not sure why you wanted to code it (maybe learn?), i created these methods.